# Find a string/word inside another string

Tags: c#, contains

I have found alot of posts similar to this issue but can't seem to find one which actually works for me.

I want to check if `string str = "blablatestblabla"` contains `string str = "test"`.
I've got this to work when there is a EXACT match. Otherwise it fails.
I have tried several methods of doing this, like;

```
Regex.IsMatch()
str.Contains()
IndexOf()
```

The purpose of this code is to find the specific string(exact match or a match within a string), add this string to a List and then continue adding the strings below until the second search string is found.

Hope you understand my problem.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
It looks like many having trouble to understand what I'm asking for so I will try make things more clear.

Let's say I have a input `List<string>`containing following;

```
fail
fail
start //Exact match (search string 1)
data 1 
data 2
end //Exact match (search string 2)
fail 
fail 

fail 
fail 
junkstartjunk //Contains "start" within the string (search string 1)
data 3
data 4
junkendjunk //Contains "end" within the string (search string 2)
fail 
fail
```

I wan't to be able to find the search string 1 (start) regardless if it is EXACT match or if it CONTAINS the match (junkstartjunk).

I want the output List to look like this;

```
start
data 1
data 2
end

junkstartjunk
data 3
data 4
junkendjunk
```

This is my code so far:

```
public void FindAndRearrangeMsg(Converter converter)
    {
        List<string> txtInput = new List<string>();
        txtInput = converter.TxtInput; // Gets the user input.
        string strFindAndArrMsg1 = converter.StrFindAndArrMsg1; // Gets the first string to search for
        string strFindAndArrMsg2 = converter.StrFindAndArrMsg2; // Gets the second string to search for
        bool msg1Found = false; // Becomes TRUE if user's first string is found
        string newLine = "\n";

        foreach (string str in txtInput)
        {
            bool firstMsg = strFindAndArrMsg1.Contains(str); // User's first specific word
            bool secondMsg = strFindAndArrMsg2.Contains(str); // User's second specific word

            if (((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) || (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))) && firstMsg && msg1Found == false)
            {
                msg1Found = true;
                outputListData.Add(str.ToString()); // Add the first string
            }
            // Continue to add string between the first and the second search string.
            else if (!secondMsg && msg1Found) 
            {
                outputListData.Add(str.ToString());
            }
            //If the second search string and the first search string is found.
            else if (secondMsg && msg1Found)
            {
                outputListData.Add(str.ToString() + newLine);
                msg1Found = false;
            }
            else
            {
                msg1Found = false;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"Hope you understand my problem."_ -- nope, not at all. The `string.Contains()` method does exactly what you _seem_ to be asking for. Please fix your question so that it has a [mcve] that shows exactly what you tried. Explain precisely both what that code does and what you want it to do instead. Explain what _specifically_ you are unable to figure out and need help with.

Comment: `str1.IndexOf("test")` returns greater than -1 if the text "test" is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked like @Eatos had the problem statement correct. But seems cleaner to do it with a single foreach loop.  The problem only requires a single bit of state to track if you're inside the part you want.

I think it's easier to do as a iterator.

It's not clear if you want the input string to contain the start/end sequence or the start/end sequence to contain the input string.  I've done it where the input strings contain the start/end.

I'm also assuming that you want to include the terminating start/end lines. Should be trivial to modify if that is not what you want.

```
    static string[] TestData = new string[]
        {
            "one","randomtwotext","three","four","five","six","seven"
        };

    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        const string start = "two";
        const string end = "six";

        var subset = GetBetween(TestData, start, end);

        foreach (var str in subset)
            Console.WriteLine(str);
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetBetween(IEnumerable<string> source, string start, string end)
    {
        bool inSequence = false;

        foreach (var str in source)
        {
            if (inSequence)
            {
                yield return str;

                if (str.Contains(end))
                    break;
            }
            else if(str.Contains(start))
            {
                yield return str;
                inSequence = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not following you code entirely to be honest. But it seems that it only checks for EXACT match? I'm looking for both EXACT match and a match within a string. I have updated my question, hopefully makes it easier to understand.

Comment: @HeXxa it's doing what I think you're asking for.  if str=="junkstartjunk" then str.Contains("start") will be true. It will also be true if str=="start".  If you look at the test data, you'll see that it contains both an exact match, and a partial match.

Comment: I tried you code but I didn't managed to make it work with my code. I'm a rookie in programming and a real newbie when it comes to IEnumerable. But I managed to make my own code work thanks to you contribution. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I belive I understand it. You want to iterate over some list of strings and create a new list which is a subset of the first one, containing only those entries which index is greater or equal the first string in the 1st list that contains some given string and keep rewriting values until You encounter a string in the 1st list that contains a second given string. Right?

If so then I would not use a `foreach` loop, it doesn't fit for the job. Use 2 `while` loops instead (if You are not going to use any `LINQ` or whatsoever).

Pseudocode:

```
 
int i = 0;
int j = inputList.length;

// Keep ignoring list elements until we either out of bounds or found a match
while(i < j && !strFindAndArrMsg1.Contains(inputList[i])) {
 i += 1;
}

// inputList[i] - 1st item in the list that contains strFindAndArrMsg1

while(i < j && !strFindAndArrMsg2.Contains(inputList[i])) {
// keep adding values to the second list...
 i += 1;
}
// ...until we are either out ou bounds or found a second match.
// inputList[i] - 1st item in the list that contains strFindAndArrMsg2
```

Depending on edge cases (do You want to include/exlude 1st/2nd found element) You might need to adjust indexes/add additional values outside of the loops.

Comment: Didn't thought of while-loops. Might be a good idea. But as I wrote in the answer above, this seems to only check for EXACT match?  I'm looking for both EXACT match and a match within a string. I have updated my question, hopefully makes it easier to understand.

Comment: One thing have to be clarified: `exact match` => `contains returns true` as in case of exact match the substring (that we look for in other string if it contains it) happens to be the same string. So both `"a".Contains("a")` and `"ab".Contains("a")` will return true. 1st is exact match, second found a substring.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to make my code work now. I'm not sure where I screwed up in the first place. Although in my example it is `strFindAndArrMsg1.Contains(str)` when it should be `str.Contains(strFindAndArrMsg1)`. But I'm pretty sure I coded it right in the beginning but made something else wrong. I'm still learning the basic of C# programming. Thank you.